# Setting TextView visible from another thread or BeginInvoke in Android

Tags: android, events, ui-thread

I'm developing an Android 2.2 application.

I have an event listener on an activity, and I want to set visible a TextView when I receive an event. But there is an error:

I only can set it visible from UI thread.

In C# and Windows Mobile there is a BeginInvoke. Is there something similar in Android?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Activity#runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) as the two easiest ways to duplicate the `BeginInvoke` functionality; with `runOnUiThread` being the one most similar.

For more complicated or performance orientated needs (i.e., you do not want to keep creating a large number of `Runnable` objects) you can use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). However, I do not recommend it as your first choice.

Comment: An article about AsyncTask and another ways to solve the problem: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html